# What kind of computer monitor do I need for a SGI O2?

Tags: display, sgi

The SGI O2 has a standard VGA port, but when I connect it to a CRT computer monitor, I do not get a signal.  Do I need a specific kind of monitor in order to use the O2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It needs to be sync-on-green capable (any good monitor should have this mentioned in the specs).

But even then you may have issues, I have a few O2's and I have observed that sometimes one of my monitors (Dell U2410, SOG capable) really distorts the colors (towards green), replugging the cable solves the issue. I had no issues with an Octane with 13W3->VGA cable.

There *are* devices on the market that can help, called sync stripper - such device could remove the sync signal from green channel and put it on the regular VGA sync line, but it might be cheaper to buy an old 15-17 inch monitor that supports SOG by default. (O2 won't do anything more than 1600x1200 without extreme tweaks anyway).

Comment: Note that "no signal" may mean a problem other than lack of sync-on-green support.  IIRC, the O2 output both SOG and standard sync, so a monitor that does not support SOG usually reacts by tinting the whole image green, rather than by not displaying anything.

Comment: @Kuba, does a 240p/480i signal on your U2410 (such as from your C64) look better with or without the XRGB-Mini? Could you explain the difference in what you see?

Comment: @traal No, it looks worse for a few reasons - U2410 doesn't have s-video so I have to use composite. The picture is stretched to the full size (1920x1200 at 16x9).